# Pandas - why does it throw ValueError?

Tags: python, pandas

Would anyone know why is Pandas throwing the ValueError and how to fix it? I just want to calculate the difference in "Value" column while grouping by "CurveName" and "Tenor"

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HAqN.png)

Comment: you need to add `.agg()` method with arguments to groupby object to be able to apply `diff` and other functions to it. Otherwise it is not clear how exactly you want to aggregate your data. See help and examples on groupby/agg method.

Comment: Where would you add agg()? I didn't know about it, will look into it

Comment: Would you know?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add .agg() method with arguments to groupby object to be able to apply diff and other functions to it. Otherwise it is not clear how exactly you want to aggregate your data. See help and examples on groupby/agg method.

here is a simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = np.random.randint(0, 4, 100)
df['b'] = np.random.randint(10, 99, 100)
df2 = df.groupby('a').agg('mean')  
df2['d'] = df2.b.diff(-1)
df2

           b          d
a                      
0  56.000000  22.500000
1  33.500000 -25.900000
2  59.400000   9.288889
3  50.111111        NaN
```

'mean' is aggregation function. Could be other like 'max', 'std' or even a custom function. Start [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)